# Accessing classes via imported classes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently working on a project where I need to import several classes from several files into `__main__.py`. However these classes need to interact with each other (ex, class A from file 1 might have to check a variable in class B from file 2). I tried doing this like such:

```
class A(object)
  (code here)
  if B.var == 1:
    pass
```

however this causes an error (B is not defined). Does anyone know a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to call `B` with a fully qualified name. If you do `import package` and `package` has a class `B` in it, then you have to check `package.B.var == 1`. You could also do `from package import B`, in which case, you could do `B.var == 1`.

Second, you need to create an object if `var` is a property rather than a static class variable. Putting these both together, you'll have something like the following:

```
import package
b_instance = package.B()
print(b_instance.var)
```

Comment: I know it is possible to import class b into class a but the variable in question will get modified frequently in the main program. If I import B and create another instance of B, var will be set to the default specified in B (and wont be affected by the program in main)

Comment: Then you need to make sure your main program has the same instance of `B`.

Comment: Is there a way to do that? Have the same instance of B in both the main file and in class A so that when you edit one it is automatically edited in the other?

Comment: If it's an instance of a class and they are indeed the same instance, then yes. A more likely approach would have a property of `A` that's an instance of `B` and directly change that property.